# Objective C running Javascript to AutoFill Webpages. Need help please

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, document

I have been stressing about this for a few hours and I cannot get it working. I have no experience in javascript and have been searching around in the forum and other sites, but I can't seem to get a solution that works.

I am trying to fill in the form using a webView in xCode

The website http://www.eatwellguide.org/mobile/ is where the form is located.

The website has this forum

```
             <form name="data[Search][form]" METHOD="post" ACTION="/search/advanced/find" ID="frmAS" >
                 <ul>
                   <li><input type="hidden" name="device" id="device" value="mobile" title="mobile">
                      <input type="hidden" name="iframe" id="iframe" value="11" title="mobile" > Keyword: </li>
                   <li><input type="text" name="data[Search][keyword]" id="SearchKeyword" title="search by keywords" /> 
                      <input ID="SearchSubmit" class="BTNsend"  type="submit" value="Find" name="data[Search][submit]"/></li>
                   <li>Zip / Postal  Code:</li>
                   <li><input type="text" title="Zip search" value="" name="data[Search][zip_code]"  />   <input ID="SearchSubmit" class="BTNsend" type="submit" value="Find" name="data[Search][submit]"/> </li>
                   <li><select name="data[Search][distance]" style="font-size:120%; ">
                         <option value="1">1</option>
                         <option value="5"  selected="">5</option>
                         <option value="10">10</option>
                         <optionvalue="20">20</option>
                         <option value="50">50</option>
                         <option value="100">100</option>
                         <option value="200">200</option>
                        </select> <input type="radio" ID="SearchDistanceUnit" value="Mi" checked="" name="data[Search][distance_unit]" class="BTNradio"/> Mi
```

I am trying to modify the textbox that i has the title = "zip search" and submit the form, but my code doesn't work at all. It won't even fill in the textbox

```
    NSString* javaScriptString = @"document.getElementById('data[Search][zip_code]').elements.value='22911';";



[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: javaScriptString];
```

It just does nothing. I have also tried GetElementsByName and many other variations of the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers support the input of JavaScript directly into the URL bar. So if you load the page you link to, then enter the following URL:

```
javascript:alert(document.getElementsByName('data[Search][zip_code]'))
```

You'll get an alert message showing what was found. In that case I've taken your `getElementByName` and corrected it — elements should be plural and it returns an array.

Building up:

```
javascript:alert(document.getElementsByName('data[Search][zip_code]')[0])
```

Evaluates to show an input element. Then:

```
javascript:alert(document.getElementsByName('data[Search][zip_code]')[0].value)
```

Shows the current value, and:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByName('data[Search][zip_code]')[0].value = '22911'
```

Populates the box. So that's the string you want (minus the `javascript:`).

If you'd taken a syntactic wrong turn, at least in Mobile Safari, your statement would be ignored. If you'd ended up trying to fetch something that isn't there you'd have received a NULL message in an alert.

Comment: Tommy you rock! Thanks for the help. How do I submit the form?